# FIWARE Orion: how to add creDate and modDate to notification from orion?

Tags: mongodb, fiware, fiware-orion

I am trying to use subscribeContext and notify (see link https://fiware-orion.readthedocs.io/en/master/user/walkthrough_apiv1/index.html#ngsi10-standard-operations)

As in mongodb, have creDate and modDate attribute, but in notifyContextRequest payload does not have these two attributes.

It's possible to include creDate and modDate attribute to notifyContextRequest payload?

Is there any way to get these attribute using Orion method?

Please see below for more details:
A row an mongodb:

```
{
    "_id" : {
        "id" : "sb1_dv1_5",
        "type" : "Call",
        "servicePath" : "/"
    },
    "attrNames" : [ 
        "status", 
        "type", 
        "to"
    ],
    "attrs" : {
        "status" : {
            "type" : "string",
            "creDate" : 1488876118,
            "modDate" : 1488876118,
            "value" : "open",
            "mdNames" : []
        },
        "type" : {
            "type" : "string",
            "creDate" : 1488876118,
            "modDate" : 1488876118,
            "value" : "video",
            "mdNames" : []
        },
        "to" : {
            "type" : "string",
            "creDate" : 1488876118,
            "modDate" : 1488876118,
            "value" : "police",
            "mdNames" : []
        }
    },
    "creDate" : 1488876118,
    "modDate" : 1488876118
}
```

Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using one of the most recent Orion versions (I think that it was introduced in 1.5.0) you can use `dateCreated` and `dateModified` in the `metadata` field within `notification` at subscription creation, eg:

```
POST /v2/subscriptions

{
   ...
   "notification": {
      ...
      "metadata": [ "dateCreated", "dateModified", "*" ]
      ...
   }
   ...
}
```

Check section "Filtering out attributes and metadata" abd "System/builtin Metadata" at [NGSIv2 latest specification](http://telefonicaid.github.io/fiware-orion/api/v2/latest/) for more detail.

**UPDATE:** the above refers to the dateCreated and dateModified *metadata* (to have creation and modification date for attrinutes). If you want dateCreated and dateModified *attributes* (to have creation and modification date for the entity as a whole) it is added in a similar way, but using `attrs` field, eg:

```
POST /v2/subscriptions

{
   ...
   "notification": {
      ...
      "attrs": [ "dateCreated", "dateModified", "*" ]
      ...
   }
   ...
}
```

Check section "Filtering out attributes and metadata" abd "System/builtin Attributes" at [NGSIv2 latest specification](http://telefonicaid.github.io/fiware-orion/api/v2/latest/) for more detail.

Comment: i am using  {
"orion": {
"version": "1.3.0",
"uptime": "10 d, 7 h, 0 m, 51 s",
"git_hash": "cb6813f044607bc01895296223a27e4466ab0913",
"compile_time": "Fri Sep 2 08:19:12 UTC 2016",
"compiled_by": "root",
"compiled_in": "ba19f7d3be65"
}
}

Comment: Is there any way to get these attribute using Orion method?

Comment: First, you should update Orion (at least to 1.5.0, although I recommend to use the lastest version by the time being, i.e. 1.7.0). Second, not sure what do you mean by "Orion method"? Do you refere how to get dateCreated/dateModified using a query to Orion (i.e. not subscription)?

Comment: First of all, Thank you so much fgalan. For the second thing, I mean if no way to add dateCreated and dateModified using subscription. do we have any way to get dateCreated, dateModified using using queryContext or other orion method?

Comment: Not sure if I understand correctly... with regards to include dateCreated and dateModified in notifications (which are sent as consequence of in place subscrrptions), it has been already answered in this post (see above). With regards to how to include dateCreated and dateModified in other places (I understand that you refer to the response to a query), please open a new question at StackOverflow (separate topics should be in separate and independent questions, for the sake of clarity). Thanks!

Comment: I tried your way. It's working now. Thank you for you worth answer.

Comment: Hi fgalan, I have another question. Maybe you can help, thanks for your times. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42860177/fiware-orion-how-to-save-an-image-png-file-to-orion