# Fiware-Orion how to save an image .png file to orion

Tags: fiware, fiware-orion

As the title, I want to save my .png file to Orion. I tried to use binary file but I got an error due to fobiden character? So It is posible to save png file to orion. Is there a best practice for the case. Many thanks

Comment: This question has been already answered: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31474823/how-to-store-an-image-from-context-broker

Comment: Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if the image is not so big you can use a data URL

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/Data_URIs

otherwise I would use an external storage mechanism and only keep in Orion a URL pointing to the object storage where your image is.

best